# What are some good code examples using checkboxes, in DisplayCode?

Tags: spring-mvc, displaytag

Can any one send me displaytag examples.

I am doing pagination using displaytag.
In pagination i am getting the rows along with check boxes once user selects the needed checkbox and submits the page.I want to get the data of the selected boxes in my controller.
How to do that,can anyone give me both jsp and controller code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://demo.displaytag.org/displaytag-examples-1.2/example-checkboxes.jsp
This shows how to use DisplayTag Checkboxes.

Also veiw this previous question. 
[displaytag, how to integrate checkboxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362009/displaytag-how-to-integrate-checkboxes)

This is about how to specifically get information from them.
http://deepeshdarshan.wordpress.com/2011/01/29/how-to-get-checkbox-values-from-displaytag-using-struts2/